# Get all elements without child node in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to select elements without child node (including text since in `<p>` text is a child node).

I used `empty`, but it also consider space as child node.

**Example:**

Markup:

```
 <span> </span>
 <span></span>
```

Script:

```
$("span:empty").html("this was empty!");
```

Unfortunately, only the second element were selected and changed since the first element has space and it was considered child node.

How do I select elements without child node? I want to consider a space as nothing. Preferably, I want the code not to use loop to select them, there might be other ways.

Comment: FYI, jQuery uses loops to filter elements from a selection. Why do you want to avoid a loop, if it can be more efficient?

Comment: @RobW jQuery uses loop and if you use loop along with it then it will be slower. Well actually I'm not after the speed, its just that I want to know if there is another way, an easier way. Loop is my last option.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

How about

```
$("span:not(:has(*))")
```

Selects all spans that have no children.

**Explanation**

The [`:has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector "selects elements which contain at least one element that matches the specified selector." The wildcard `*` means all elements.

> The expression `$('div:has(p)')` matches a `<div>` if a `<p>` exists
>   anywhere among its descendants, not just as a direct child.

The [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector "selects all elements that do not match the given selector."

In this case, `:has()` selects everything and then we use `:not()` to find the elements that don't match "everything"... in other words, nothing.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WrHtg/1/)

Comment: @dpp not sure why you changed your accept to this, this is completely wrong. Even in the demo it selects 2 spans that have text inside them. Any explanation? :O

Comment: @Esailija I'm sorry, but it's actually what I'm looking for, I said I want to consider " " and text (including text since in <p> a text is a child node) as nothing. Your answer is helpful, in fact I learned about `expr`.

Comment: @dpp oh, that would have been so much easier :D

Answer (score 9):

```
$.expr[":"]["no-children"] = function( elem ) {
    return !elem.firstChild || !$.trim(""+ elem.firstChild.nodeValue);
};
$("span:no-children").html("this was empty");
```

​

http://jsfiddle.net/k5eTS/6/

There was a surprising "feature" with jQuery's `$.trim` that converts `null` to `""` while I was expecting `"null"`. Converting to string manually fixes this.

Comment: Thanks for a quick response! Hm, is there any alternative methods which is just as easier as `empty`? Look, your solution is great, its just that I want to know if there is such filter like `$("span:noChildren")`.

Comment: @dpp You can create an own selector using `$.expr`

Answer (score 4):

I think you can try this:

```
$('span').filter(function() {
   return !this.innerHTML.replace(/\s/g,'').length;
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TkfVP/1/)**

Comment: Every element in html has '' no matter what is written inside it

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("span").each(function(){
if($(this).text().trim()=='')
$(this).text('Empty');
});
```

If you don't like each function then

```
$("span").html(function(){
if($(this).text().trim()=='')
return 'Empty';
});
```