# Delete Table with No Rows in HTML

Tags: javascript

I have a html page that has table with table heading.
I want to delete the table on load if it does not contain any rows on loading the document.Please mind that I do not want to click or any other things.

```
<table class="Example:">
<th>Range from 12.12 to 1.12</th></table>
<table class="Range:">
 <th>Range from109.091to111.364</th>  <tr><td>f88c6441-3a2f-4c63-8b00-f63a75c09d57</td>
  <td class="number">110.000</td></tr>
</table>
```

I want to delete the first table and keep the second. Mind that there can be dynamic number of such tables

Comment: You haven't got any rows added on the table above, a <tr> needs to wrapped around the <th>. Also what have you done so far?

Comment: Apparently tr does not need to be wraped around th
This is code copied from source. table has a heading and then has one row in 2nd case

Comment: The accepted answer is using jQuery, but is not jQuery tagged...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With jquery:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('table').each(function(){
      if($(this).find('td').length <= 0){
         $(this).remove();
       }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: No. you need to use different classes $('.tableClass') / ids $('#tableID') or table indexes $('table:eq(indexNumberHere)') for selector.

Comment: But this is dynamically generated tables. There can be any number of tables . Is there a way to check every table with a given class name and delete or hide it ?

Comment: Just one last thing. I am trying to specify this using class name and it does not work
    $('.classname').each ...
is the above wrong

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `tr` element outside the `th`.

You can get the number of rows of the table and if bigger than 1 (first is the heading) hide the table.

Code:

```
var rowCount = document.getElementsByClassName('Example')[0].rows.length;

if (rowCount<=1){
     document.getElementsByClassName('Example')[0].style.display = 'none';
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/HLv9c/

Answer (score 1):

Use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) :

```
$("table:not(:has(td))").remove();
```

[Get all elements without child node in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11061594/get-all-elements-without-child-node-in-jquery)

Javascript :

```
var table = document.getElementsByTagName("table");

for (var i = 0, a = table[i]; i < table.length; i++, a = table[i]) {
    if (a.getElementsByTagName("td").length === 0) {
        a.parentElement.removeChild(a);
    }
}
```

Demo : http://jsbin.com/vuzin/1/edit