# Print each string if it contains a specific character in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get all the strings which contains a specific word in it,
for example:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <span>
            <h3>In Paris (Mark Bartels) worked for about 50 years.</h3>
        </span>
    </div>

    <div>
        <span>
            <h3>In America (Henry Bartels) worked for about 50 years.</h3>
        </span>
    </div>

    <div>
        <span>
            <h3>In Europe (Mark Bartels) worked for about 50 years.</h3>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

In above string I have to check for "Mark", now I want to show all the strings which contains the word "Mark".

I have tried something in the following way but it doesn't help me.

```
var elem = $('body').find(':contains(Mark)').not('script, style, link');
var a = elem.parent();
var tag = a;
console.log(tag);
$("#sentence").append(elem.text());
$("#sentence").append('<br />');
```

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/nt6oktkz/

Comment: what does php has to do with this?

Comment: This will be your answer. `$(":not(:contains('Mark'))").hide();`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Iterate over all the elements that contains string and append the innerText.

1. `:not(:has(*))`: Selects all the elements that have no child element(excluding the text nodes) [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11061594/get-all-elements-without-child-node-in-jquery)
2. `:contains(Mark)')`: Selects all the elements that contains text `Mark`
3. `:not(script)`: To exclude the `<script>` elements

```js
// Get all the h3 elements which contains `Mark` in the innerText
// Iterate over them
$('body').find(':not(:has(*)):contains(Mark):not(script)').each(function() {
  // Append to the element
  console.log($(this)[0]);
  $('#sentence').append($(this).text() + '<br />');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div>
    <span>
      <h3>In Paris (Mark Bartels) worked for about 50 years.</h3>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>
      <h3>In America (Henry Bartels) worked for about 50 years.</h3>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>
      <h3>In Europe (Mark Bartels) worked for about 50 years.</h3>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="sentence"></div>
```

Comment: hi, yes it works, but i dont want to restrict it only for h3, as html tag can be different, so is there any way to Iterate it by all the html tags?

Comment: try using `*` instead of `h3` like `$('#container').find('*:contains(Mark)')`

Comment: i tried, but it prints all the text, instead of the required one

Comment: what about 'body' inplace of '#container', because there is not id in my case, i have to use body

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume the `h3` have a common class `text`,  then we can use `indexof` to easily figure out the places where `Mark` occurs

```
$('.text').each(function () {
    if ($(this).text().indexOf('Mark') >= 0) {
        $("#sentence").append($(this).text() + '<br />');
    }
});
```

Comment: Dude I just tried to focus on use of `indexOf`. I know all you points are valid.