# Switching classes using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm creating a simple tile game for class. What I am trying to do is:

1. Inside the parent div is a child class 'square' that if clicked, the square is appended to the parent with the class 'empty'
2. I need the parent that had the child to now be class 'empty' and the now occupied parent to have the class 'full'

The current problem I'm having is the children keep appending to the class the class 'empty', and that class is not switching.

I looked here: [Get all elements without child node in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11061594/get-all-elements-without-child-node-in-jquery)

and here: http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

and here is my code pen : http://codepen.io/super996/pen/vyQyxN

```
// when page loads all parent divs are clickable to .empty class div
$('document').ready(function () {


 for (let i = 0; i < $('.parent').children().length; i += 1) {
$('.square').click(function () {
  $(this).appendTo('.empty');
  });
  }
});

$('parent:has(.full)').click(function (event) {
  $(event.target).toggleClass('.empty', true);
      });
      });

if ($('.square').click === true) {
  //parent of sqaure gets class empty and destination of square
  //parent gets class full
  }
```

EDIT: I'm in he process of trying this..

```
if ($('.full:first-child').click(function (){
$('.full:first-child').removeClass('.')
```

});

Comment: Your question is clear . Also your code is confusing/ wrong like why do you need `for (let i = 0; i < $('.parent').children().length; i += 1)` ?

Comment: that was to add the click function to all my squares

Comment: No need of a for loop then : `$('.square')` will select all the elements on the dom with square class and then you can attach event to tham

Comment: $('.parent').on('click', function(){}); will do that without a for loop

Comment: I tried the $(.'square) and ditched the for loop but , that appended all squares of class 'square' to the empty parent div

Answer (score 0):

So I am a little fuzzy on how you're trying to accomplish this, but it looks like you want to switch classes from `.full` to `.empty` when a full tile is clicked and add the `.full` class to the empty tile. For this you can try by delegating events to the children of `#board`

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $board = $('#board'); //Cache the board

  $board.on('click', 'div.full', function(){
    $board.find('div.empty').removeClass('empty').addClass('full');
    $(this).addClass('empty').removeClass('full');
  });

});
```

This should help you without doing the entire assignment for you ;)
Now all you need to do is figure out where to switch from `.addClass` and `.removeClass` to `.appendTo` and `.empty`

Comment: To understand, "find the div with class full and the callback function is the swap." To try and work a solution I went into devtools and was using javascript to try to get the parents and children hoping that would get it. Thanks Daniel!

Comment: yep, you got it

Answer (score 0):

this is my complete javascript code.

maybe you can try replace your script with this

```
// when page loads all parent divs are clickable to .empty class div
$('document').ready(function () {
  $('.square').click(function () {
      var parent = $(this).parent('div');
      $(this).appendTo('.empty');
      $('.empty').addClass('full').removeClass('empty');
      parent.addClass('empty').removeClass('full');
    });
});
```